# Classification of OLS regression coefficients

Tags: classification, regression, bayesian

A variable $A$ (reaction time) is log-normally distributed, i.e. $\log(A) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and is linearly dependent of $n$ variables $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, i.e.
\begin{align}
A &= \alpha_1 X_1 + \alpha_2 X_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n X_n + \epsilon,
\end{align}
where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau^2)$. An observation of variable $A$ belongs either to class 1 or to class 0, denoted as $A^1$ or $A^0$. I splitted my training observations on $A^1$ and $A^0$ (balanced ratio) and used an OLS model to find two sets of coefficients $\hat{\alpha}^1$ and $\hat{\alpha}^0$ such that $\hat{\alpha}^1 X$ and $\hat{\alpha}^0 X$ estimate $A^1$ and $A^0$ with minimal errors.

Now, I want to make a class prediction for new observations $A,X$. How to classify such an observation?

One way forward could be a Bayesian approach, since I know the class priors $p(D^i)$ equal roughly $0.5$. But how to compute the conditional class distributions $p(A|D^i,X)$ and the posterior $p(\hat{\alpha}^i|A,X)$ $i=0,1$?

What would you suggest?

Comment: What is your ultimate aim? Classification of $A$? Why do you use OLS and not Logit?

Comment: The main reason to avoid logistic regression is that $A$ is part of a mediation model*, i.e. $X \rightarrow \hat{\alpha} \rightarrow A$

* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)